# Two ports of the same PowerBank on series

Tags: power-supply

I have a power bank with 2 USB ports, each one is a 5V/2A, is it possible to put the two ports on serie so I can have a 10V/2A output?

Comment: Without any diagrams I would go with NO.

Comment: Most likely the "power bank" has a common ground provided to each USB port; if so, you cannot connect these in series.

Comment: You need an isolated supply to stack power supplies like this, usb hubs supplies are never isolated (i've never seen one). Get a AC DC converter

Comment: if you have 2 banks you can do just that, but not with just 2 ports on 1 bank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The PSU will most likely have one voltage regulator giving out 5 V. This is split to feed two USB sockets, each with a connection to +5 and GND.

If you try to series connect these you will connect the +5 of one to the GND of the other and short-circuit the supply. If the thing has proper individual current limiting on each port then the other port may continue to give out 5 V. Otherwise the regulator will go into current limit and shut down.